# VBA Autofilter - filter out everything that is older than today

Tags: excel, vba, filter, autofilter

I hava some future Data, and I need to filter out this data as soon as it becmoes outdated based on yesterday's date. I used macro record to see ho to filter out by date, and I used the code to make a small script.

The problem is that when I run the code from macro myself, all the data is filtering out, instead of the outdated.

```
     Dim WS_Count As Integer
     Dim I As Integer

     ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
     ' workbook.
     WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

     ' Begin the loop.
     For I = 1 To WS_Count

        ' Insert your code here.
        ' The following line shows how to reference a sheet within
        ' the loop by displaying the worksheet name in a dialog box.
        Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I)
        A1 = ws.Range("A1").Value
        If (InStr(A1, "HEDGE POSITION") <> 0) And ws.AutoFilterMode = True Then

            Dat = CStr(Date - 1)
            datt = ">" & Dat
            MsgBox datt
            ws.Range("$A$4:$P$40").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:= _
            datt, Operator:=xlAnd
        End If

     Next I
```

So this is the code recorded by macro recorder. It doesn't work when I run it myself (all data vanishes)

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4:$P$40").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:= _
    ">16/12/2019", Operator:=xlAnd
```

EDIT:

I have noticed that it works if instead of writing "16/12/2020" I write "12/16/2020" (swapping the position of month and date )

But I get the date from VBA's date function, and my dates are in format "day/month/year". So it should fit the date format from VBA's Date().

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Usually one would use a `Long` data type to filter dates because of the issues that come with local setting. As you noticed the filter would otherwise want's to use a particular format.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using Format, [Dat = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yy")]:

```
     Dim WS_Count As Integer
     Dim I As Integer

     ' Set WS_Count equal to the number of worksheets in the active
     ' workbook.
     WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

     ' Begin the loop.
     For I = 1 To WS_Count

        ' Insert your code here.
        ' The following line shows how to reference a sheet within
        ' the loop by displaying the worksheet name in a dialog box.
        Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(I)
        A1 = ws.Range("A1").Value
        If (InStr(A1, "HEDGE POSITION") <> 0) And ws.AutoFilterMode = True Then


            Dat = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yy")

            datt = ">" & Dat

            ws.Range("$A$4:$P$40").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:= _
            datt, Operator:=xlAnd
        End If

     Next I
```